# Hola necesito ayuda al querer desarrollar un ejercicio

Tags: c++, poo

Tengo un problema me sale este error en codeblocks me sale el error

> 'vsnprinf' help please y Ld returned 1 exit status

ademas quisiera ayuda en el paso de un parámetro de tipo objeto a una función ajena de una clase como se muestra en la parte final del ejercicio, en realidad en mi debuger de codeblocks no me manifiesta errores de codigo asi que no puede ver exactamente porque no me compila
El ejercicio es el siguiente.

Haz una clase llamada Persona que siga las siguientes condiciones:

Sus atributos son: nombre, edad, DNI, sexo (H hombre, M mujer), peso y altura. No queremos que se accedan directamente a ellos. Piensa que modificador de acceso es el más adecuado, también su tipo. Si quieres añadir algún atributo puedes hacerlo.
Por defecto, todos los atributos menos el DNI serán valores por defecto según su tipo (0 números, cadena vacía para String, etc.). Sexo sera hombre por defecto, usa una constante para ello.
Se implantaran varios constructores:
Un constructor por defecto.
Un constructor con el nombre, edad y sexo, el resto por defecto.
Un constructor con todos los atributos como parámetro.
Los métodos que se implementaran son:
calcularIMC(): calculara si la persona esta en su peso ideal (peso en kg/(altura^2  en m)), si esta fórmula devuelve un valor menor que 20, la función devuelve un -1, si devuelve un número entre 20 y 25 (incluidos), significa que esta por debajo de su peso ideal la función devuelve un 0  y si devuelve un valor mayor que 25 significa que tiene sobrepeso, la función devuelve un 1. Te recomiendo que uses constantes para devolver estos valores.
esMayorDeEdad(): indica si es mayor de edad, devuelve un booleano.
comprobarSexo(char sexo): comprueba que el sexo introducido es correcto. Si no es correcto, sera H. No sera visible al exterior.
toString(): devuelve toda la información del objeto.
generaDNI(): genera un número aleatorio de 8 cifras, genera a partir de este su número su letra correspondiente. Este método sera invocado cuando se construya el objeto. Puedes dividir el método para que te sea más fácil. No será visible al exterior.
Métodos set de cada parámetro, excepto de DNI.
Ahora, crea una clase ejecutable que haga lo siguiente:

Pide por teclado el nombre, la edad, sexo, peso y altura.
Crea 3 objetos de la clase anterior, el primer objeto obtendrá las anteriores variables pedidas por teclado, el segundo objeto obtendrá todos los anteriores menos el peso y la altura y el último por defecto, para este último utiliza los métodos set para darle a los atributos un valor.
Para cada objeto, deberá comprobar si esta en su peso ideal, tiene sobrepeso o por debajo de su peso ideal con un mensaje.
Indicar para cada objeto si es mayor de edad.
Por último, mostrar la información de cada objeto.
Puedes usar métodos en la clase ejecutable, para que os sea mas fácil.

````
  #include <conio.h>  
  #include <stdio.h>  
  #include <string>  
  #include<math.h> 
  #define SEXO_DEF 'H'   
  #define INFRAPESO -1  
  #define PESO_IDEAL 0  
 #define SOBREPESO 1

  using namespace std;  

  class persona  
  {  

  private:  
   string nombre;  
   string DNI;  
   int edad;  
   char sexo;  
   float peso;  
   float altura;  

  public:  

   persona();  
   persona(string,int,char);  
   persona(string,int,char,float,float);  
   void comprobarSexo();  
   void generarDNI();  
   char generaLetraDNI(int res);  
   void setNombre(string nombre);  
   void setEdad(int edad);  
   void setSexo(char sexo);  
   void setPeso(float peso);  
   void setAltura(float altura);  
   int calcularIMC();  
   bool esMayorDeEdad();  
   void toString();  
  };  

  persona::persona()  
  {  
     persona("",0,SEXO_DEF,0,0);  
  }  
  persona::persona(string _nombre,int _edad,char _sexo)  
  {  
      persona(_nombre,_edad,_sexo,0,0);  
  }  

  persona::persona(string _nombre,int _edad, char _sexo,float _peso,float _altura)  
  {  
      nombre=_nombre;  
      edad=_edad;  
      sexo=_sexo;  
      altura=_altura;  
      generarDNI();  
      peso=_peso;  
      comprobarSexo();  
  }  

  void persona::comprobarSexo()  
  {  
      if(sexo!='H' && sexo!='M')  
      {  
          sexo='H';  
      }  
      cout<<sexo;    
  }  

  void persona::generarDNI()  
  {  
   int divisor=23;  
   int numDNI=int(floor(rand()*(100000000-10000000)+10000000));  
   cout<<numDNI;  
   int res=int(numDNI-int(numDNI/divisor*divisor));  
   char letraDNI=generaLetraDNI(res);  
   std::string dni=std::to_string(numDNI)+letraDNI;  

  }  

  char persona::generaLetraDNI(int _res)  
  {  
   char letras[23]= {'T', 'R', 'W', 'A', 'G', 'M', 'Y','F', 'P', 'D', 'X', 'B', 'N', 'J', 'Z',
                     'S', 'Q', 'V', 'H', 'L', 'C', 'K', 'E'  
                    };  
   return letras[_res];  
  }  

  void persona::setNombre(string _nombre)  
  {  
   nombre=_nombre;  
  }  

  void persona::setEdad(int _edad)  
  {  
   edad=_edad;  
  }  

  void persona::setSexo(char _sexo)  
  {  
   sexo=_sexo;  
  }  

  void persona::setPeso(float _peso)  
  {  
   peso=_peso;  
  }  

  void persona::setAltura(float _altura)  
  {  
   altura=_altura;  
  }  

  int persona::calcularIMC()  
  {  
   float pesoActual=float(peso/pow(altura,2));  
   if(pesoActual>=20 && pesoActual<=25)  
   {  
       return PESO_IDEAL;  
   }  
   else if(pesoActual<20)  
   {  
       return INFRAPESO;  
   }  
   else  
   {   
       return SOBREPESO;  
   }  
  }  

  bool persona::esMayorDeEdad()  
  {  
   bool mayor=false;  
   if(edad>=18)  
   {  
       mayor=true;  
   }  
   return mayor;  
  }  

  void persona::toString()  
  {  
   string _sexo;  
   if(sexo=='H')  
   {  
       _sexo="hombre";  
   }  
   else  
   {  
       _sexo="mujer";  
   }  
   cout<<"Informacion de la persona: "<<endl  
               <<"Nombre: "<<nombre<<endl  
               <<"Edad: "<<edad<<endl  
               <<"Sexo: "<<_sexo<<endl  
               <<"DNI: "<<endl  
               <<"Peso: "<<peso<<endl  
               <<"Altura: "<<altura;  
  }  

  void MuestraMensajePeso(persona);  
  void MuestraMayorEdad(persona);  

  int main()  
  {  

   persona persona1=persona();  

   persona1.setNombre("Laura");  
   persona1.setEdad(30);  
   persona1.setSexo('M');  
   persona1.setPeso(60);  
   persona1.setAltura(1.60);  

   cout<<"Persona 1"<<endl;  
   MuestraMensajePeso(persona1);  
   MuestraMayorEdad(persona1);  
   persona1.toString();  

   return 0;  
  }  

  void MuestraMensajePeso(persona _persona)  
  {  
   int IMC=_persona.calcularIMC();  
   switch(IMC)  
   {  
   case 0:  
       cout<<"La persona esta en su peso ideal"<<endl; 
       break;  
   case -1:  
       cout<<"La persona esta por debajo de su peso ideal"<<endl;  
       break;  
   case 1: 
       cout<<"La persona esta por encima de su peso ideal"<<endl;  
       break;  
   }  
  }  

  void MuestraMayorEdad(persona _persona)  
  {  
   if(_persona.esMayorDeEdad())  
   {   
       cout<<"La persona es mayor de edad";  
   }  
   else  
   {  
       cout<<"La persona no es mayor de edad";  
   }  
  }```
````

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola!

No comprendí bien a qué te refieres con esto:

> ademas quisiera ayuda en el paso de un parámetro de tipo objeto a una función ajena de una clase como se muestra en la parte final del ejercicio

Si fueras más específico podría ayudarte mejor.

Por otro lado, incluyendo la siguiente línea, el código a mí me funcionó:

```
#include<iostream>
```

Si no la incluyes, el compilador no reconocerá ni a `cout` ni a `endl` y eso te dará errores de compilación. Si estás teniendo problemas con tu IDE, te comento que el que yo uso para programar en C++ es DEV-C++ y/o Eclipse.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: en realidad  si puse el #include<iostream> solo que me olvide de copiarlo, al parecer creo que es mi id

Comment: y a lo de paso de parametro me referia a que tengo dos funciones  void MuestraMensajePeso(persona);  
  void MuestraMayorEdad(persona);  no se enrealidad si estoy pasando correctamente el parametro persona que es una clase en realidad

Comment: En las líneas en las que declaras los prototipos de las funciones, necesitas declararlas de la forma: ```[tipo de retorno] nombre_de_funcion([tipo/s_de_parametros])```. En el prototipado no se suele especificar el nombre que tomarán los parámetros, sólo se ponen los tipos (los nombres se suelen poner cuando se desarrolla el cuerpo de la función). Tú, por ejemplo, pones ```void MuestraMensajePeso(persona)``` haciendo referencia simplemente a que recibirás un objeto del tipo ```persona```, no a qué nombre le darás para trabajar con ella dentro de la función.

Comment: Por otro lado, cuando desarrollas la función, le asignas un nombre a este objeto como hiciste: ```void MuestraMayorEdad(persona _persona)```, indicando que **_persona** es el nombre que tendrá el objeto dentro de esta función. Tanto el prototipado como el desarrollo de la función están bien.

Comment: entonces creo que el error se centra en mi ide codeblocks

Comment: Te recomiendo probar el IDE DEV-C++, es muy liviano, robusto, intuitivo y fácil de configurar. Personalmente, nunca usé CodeBlocks, así que no podría ayudarte con ello. A mí me funcionó. Cualquier consulta estoy dispuesto a ayudar. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: ok muchas gracias

Comment: aproposito que tipo de compilador utilizas con el IDE

Comment: Yo uso ```TDM-GCC (MinGW compiler) 4.9.2```, para 64 bits.